# AWS Storage on heroku lose images rails 5 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, paperclip

Thanks for helping. 
I have my app: http://www.lapapaya.org/dreams hosted on heroku 
My app is using rails 5.0.1, this is my gemfile: 
https://gist.github.com/pipevel/4d86dbf6429a44b6d28f6dc233c45a8a
I'm using:

```
gem "paperclip", '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.59.0'
```

To store images, I have an in AWS. 
I made the update of my site and now the images i had uploaded doesn't appear, i see a broken link with the direction to the aws server. 
In my logs in heroku i see:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/dreams/images/000/000/567/medium/images.jpg"):
```

¿Any idea of how to solve this error?

I just tried assets:precompile and also this line in my production.rb:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

Comment: `i see a broken link with the direction to the aws server.`I guess is something from your AWS Bucket config. (Perhaps I really recommend you using carrierwave instead of paperclip.)

I would recommend you checking this great tutorial on how to configure correctly AWS Buckets and IAM permissions with heroku in Rails 5

https://medium.com/alturasoluciones/setting-up-rails-5-active-storage-with-amazon-s3-3d158cf021ff

Comment: Thanks! I will see this tutorial.

Comment: Does images appear locally?

Comment: No, it doesn't appear. I followed the instructions of this tutorial and installed activestorage. No i have this error: Module::DelegationError in Pages#userpanel url delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil       '<div class="useravatar">
        <% if current_user.avatar.present? %>
          <%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>
        <% else %>
          <img src="assets/images/missing_avatar.png" />
        <% end %>'

Comment: ¿Activestorage does the same job as carrierwave?

Comment: I found the answer here: https://medium.com/epfl-extension-school/moving-from-carrierwave-to-activestorage-in-a-rails-app-31f13e3ff37d so i think it's better solution using activestorage. My local app is running but i cant log in because the system drop an error: [link](https://gist.github.com/pipevel/f0853eb59aafefaa041af57925d4873d)